# Reading data from multiple pubusb to same bigquery

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

This question is more related to understand the syntax to connect gcp pipeline in apache beam. here is how my current pipeline is setup

```
options = dataflow_options(project_id=project_id, topic_name=topic_name, job_name=job_name)

p = apache_beam.Pipeline(options=options)

(p
    | 'read pubusb' >> apache_beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=topic_path, with_attributes=True)
    | 'decode the message' >> apache_beam.ParDo(mydecoder())
    | 'persist to db' >> apache_beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            output_table,
            create_disposition=apache_beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=apache_beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
))

p.run()
```

With this i am able to create a pipeline which look slike this .

[image]

Now what i actually want to do (given that my decoder is the same) is to connect multiple pubsub to same decoder i.e.,

[image]

How can i achieve this in apache beam

**Few things that i forgot to mention**

1. All topics are basically byte stream.
2. There is no common key between data when reading from topics
3. Each topic will have a different logic to decode

I was looking at `CoGroupby` but it needs a common key.

Comment: You can use [flatten](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#flatten) to combine multiple PCollections into one. But how do you want to decide which decoder to use for which message (you mention the decoding logic is different for each topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flatten](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#flatten) to combine multiple PCollections into one:

```
# Flatten takes a tuple of PCollection objects.
# Returns a single PCollection that contains all of the elements in the PCollection objects in that tuple.

 merged = (
     (pcoll1, pcoll2, pcoll3)
     # A list of tuples can be "piped" directly into a Flatten transform.
     | beam.Flatten())
```

Comment: hey - i  am stuck with a new problem when i tried using `Flatten`. I posted the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937654/passing-input-to-flatten-and-getting-output-for-bigquery

Comment: It seems your other post is gone. Did you solve your problem?